# "Unable to launch a new process" in Laravel production application

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, production

```
[2023-02-23 17:07:02] production.ERROR: Unable to launch a new process. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to launch a new process. at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:342)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php(236): Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Process->start(NULL, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php(218): Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Process->run()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php(195): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\Event->runCommandInForeground(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php(111): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\Event->run(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php(75): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\ScheduleRunCommand->runEvent(Object(Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\Event))
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\ScheduleRunCommand->handle()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(576): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\ScheduleRunCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(90): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(133): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#18 /var/www/html/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#19 {main}
"}
```

I have tried googling, on laracast and github forum but no luck. I also have no idea if this is a severe
for production or not.

Comment: I see it is related to the `php artisan schedule:run` command, but I have never saw that error

Comment: There might be a restriction on starting new processes or a limit of processes on your server that you've reached. Try rebooting your production server to see if the problem still occurs (which might indicate a permission issue) or if it starts occuring again after some time (which might indicate a resource leak somewhere)